# Minimun k-union from a different angle

Tags: algorithms, optimization, np-hard, combinatorics

I'm looking for work done on solving some problem which is very similar to the [minimum k-union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424155/given-n-sets-of-elements-find-minimal-union-of-m-sets).

The problem:

There's a set of elements $E=\{e_1,e_2,...,e_k\}$ of size $k$, and a family of sets $S_1,S_2,...,S_t$ where each set $S_i$ is contained in $E$: $S_i \subseteq E$.

The objective is to find for each $1 \leq j\leq k$ the "best" subset of $E$ of size $j$, where "best" means that it has the biggest number of sets $S_i$ which are contained in it.
The problem, as well as it being NP-hard, is described [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96272/is-this-problem-np-hard-maximizing-selected-sets-so-that-their-union-is-less-th) too.

I could use solutions to the minimum k-union to solve this, but that wouldn't be ideal regarding computation time, so hopefully this problem can be reduced to some problem that has approximation algorithms to it.